# Django models.py error(about ManyToManyField)

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class WorkDailyRecord(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    contents = models.TextField()
    check_user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    target_user = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    ONGOING_OR_END =(
            ('ing', '진행중'),
            ('end', '완료'),
        )


    ongoing_or_end = models.CharField(
            max_length=3,
            choices=ONGOING_OR_END,
            default='ing',
        )
```

I write that code, then I'm give error...

So I search the Internet, and I find out that I must use 'related_name' attribute.

But I don't know why I must use that attr??

**Why??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting up an M2M to the `User` model, `User` instances will have an automatic `workdailyrecord_set` attribute set on them. Since you need 2 accessors, django complains since it can't set `workdailyrecord_set` twice.

If they allowed it, it would be very confusing indeed, as who knows what `user.workdailyrecord_set` would return in that case.

You need to give it a [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name) to differentiate between the two relationships pointing to `User`.

```
target_user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='workdailyrecord_target')
check_user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='workdailyrecord_check')
```

This way, `User` instances will have a `workdailyrecord_target` reverse manager which will only query `WorkDailyRecord` objects related to `User` by the `target_user` relationship.

e.g.

```
User.objects.latest('id').workdailyrecord_target.all()  
#  all WorkDailyRecords where user is referenced by 'target_user'

User.objects.latest('id').workdailyrecord_check.all()
 #  all WorkDailyRecords where user is referenced by 'target_check'
```

Unfortunately, you cannot disable this feature even using django's documented `related_name='+'` feature when it comes to M2Ms. Don't ask me why :)